# Store Native Storage value into variable

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to store a native storage value (that I fetch) into a variable to use it in my POST's datas, but my code actually returns nothing...

Here, I fetch my value and store it into a previously defined variable, but this is not working..

```
  bookChef(chef) {
    var customer = "";
    this.nativeStorage.getItem('userCredentials')
      .then(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          customer = data.id;
    });
    console.log(customer);
}
```

My `console.log(customer)` doesn't return an integer as expected..
Does anyone know how to handle it ?

Comment: The first console.log to execute will be the one outside the `.then` block and it will log an empty string. If there is no error, the second log will execute and will log the `data` object. Does the second log execute?

Comment: The `console.log(customer)` statement will log an empty string because the function assigns `customer` the value of an empty string (`""`). The `console.log(data)` statement will execute later (assuming there is no error) because it is inside a `.then` block. Does the `console.log(data)` statement execute?

Comment: But I need to use my customer variable later out of my ``then()`` function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I need to use my customer variable later out of my `.then()` function

Save the promise that the `.then` method returns:

```
this.customerPromise  = this.nativeStorage.getItem('userCredentials')
.then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    var customer = data.id;
    console.log(customer);
    return customer;
},error => {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
});
```

Then later use that promise to [chain](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises) other actions:

```
//LATER
this.customerPromise.then( customer => {
    console.log(customer);
    // DO other stuff
});
```

Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises. It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - The Promise API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api)
- [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're are getting the credentials, then straight away trying to use them. You call console.log before nativeStorage even has a chance to get the value.

You need to move your code that is using the credentials into the then callback.

```
this.nativeStorage.getItem('userCredentials')
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    var customer = data.id;
    console.log(customer);
  });
```

Comment: But I need to use my customer variable later out of my then() function...